# Get all file from blob directory timeout 400 error when having large number of file

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

On C# trying to access all files from azure blob directory and getting error when we have large number of files approxe 5000

```
  var Container = SectionrootStatic.GetSection("storage:container:name").Value;
            Container = Container + "/" + FolderName;
            CloudBlobContainer container = BlobUtilities.GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobDirectory dr = container.GetDirectoryReference(FolderName);
         
            var listallFiles = dr.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100000, null, null, null).Result;
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete error message as text.